# One page divided in 2 columns in bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have one page divided into 2 columns in bootstrap3 Here is what it looks like:

[image]

How do I make that image using bootstrap 3 ? (I need the code for that image using bootstrap 3)

Comment: SO is not fot code request..show your effort.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean ?

Comment: I mean you should try something on your own then if you are having any specific problem we can help you.. but you can't ask us to code for you

Comment: thanks ... but if you have any ideas on how to make it then please tell me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it like this--

WRAP your content within two same width column both of which should be inside a row div

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
           <style type="text/css">
            
           </style>
           </head>
           <body>
          <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-xs-6" style="background-color: red; height:300px;"></div>
         <div class="col-xs-6" style="background-color: blue; height:300px;"></div>
        
</div>
            </body>
  </html>
```

Try this tutorials to learn about bootstrap--

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer